# SML - Build a new list with the elements of the original list - Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]

Tags: sml, smlnj

Given a list of numbers , I want to create a new list where the element at index `i`
is the sum of all the `i-1` elements before .

For example :

```
[1,4,6,9] ->  [1,5,11,20]
```

I've written the following code :

```
fun sum nil = 0 
| sum [x]=x 
| sum(x::rest)=(x+hd(rest))::sum(rest);
```

but I got this :

```
- fun sum nil = 0
= | sum [x]=x
= | sum(x::rest)=(x+hd(rest))::sum(rest);
stdIn:306.16-306.39 Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: int * int list
  operand:         int * int
  in expression:
    x + hd rest :: sum rest
```

I can see that the recursive rule of `(x+hd(rest))::sum(rest);` is the reason for 
the problem , but how can I fix it ?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your base cases. You want the function to return a list, so the base cases should return lists.

```
fun sum []      = []
  | sum [x]     = [x]
  | sum (x::xs) = ...
```

I replaced `nil` with `[]` because I like it better - it doesn't really matter.

Another thing - never use the `hd` and `tl` operators (there are exceptions, but for now, just don't). Sure, in your function, it won't become a problem because you took care of the case where it would, but there's another reason. If you do this:

```
fun foo [] = ...
  | foo (x::y::xs) = ...
```

SML will *tell* you that the pattern matching is not exhaustive, that is, there are patterns you've missed, which means you catch the error at compile-time and not at run-time.

Here's a version of your function that works.

```
fun sum [] = []
  | sum [x] = [x]
  | sum (x::y::xs) = x::sum (x+y::xs)
```

I moved the addition to the recursive call because if you add as the first thing, then the first element of the result will be the first *two* elements of the original list added together.